# ANTLR: Invalid grammar - No viable alternative at input

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to build a simple grammar, but without success. I read ANTLR official docs but can't figure out what is the problem.  The following code is the grammar.

```
grammar Splitter;

splitter : statements EOF;
statements : statement statement*;
statement: (yieldStatement | variableDeclarationStatement | forStatement) ';';
block : '{' statements? '}';

yieldStatement: 'yield' expression;

variableDeclarationStatement: VariableDeclaratorId '=' expression;
VariableDeclaratorId: Identifier;

forStatement: 'for' VariableDeclaratorId 'in' forIterable block;
forIterable: expression;

methodInvocation: MethodName '(' argumentList? ')';
MethodName: Identifier;
argumentList: argumentName (',' argumentName)*;
argumentName: expression;

expression: objectExpression | numericExpression | textExpression | variableAcessor | methodInvocation;
variableAcessor: VariableDeclaratorId ('[' expression ']')*;

objectExpression: '{' keyValueStatementList? '}';
keyValueStatementList: keyValueStatement (',' keyValueStatement)*;
keyValueStatement: keyStatement ':' valueStatement;
keyStatement: textExpression;
valueStatement: expression;

Identifier: [a-zA-Z_]+;

numericExpression : IntegerLiteral;
IntegerLiteral : [0-9]+;

textExpression : '"' StringCharacters? '"';
StringCharacters: StringCharacter StringCharacter*;
fragment StringCharacter: ~["\\] | EscapeSequence;
fragment EscapeSequence: '\\' [btnfr"'\\];

SPACE: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

My tests are very simple inputs, that don't use all the grammar, like *yield 1;*, *yield "a";* and *DATA = {"key": "Hello world"}; yield DATA;*.

Anyone?

Comment: If you mean that e.g. `yield 1` (as opposed to the entire sample string) fails, then that first example appears to be missing a `;` at the end that your grammar demands on `statement`.

Comment: Sorry, i missed it :)  My tests contains ';' in te end.  Fixed it.  Thanks!